# Merge name-clash and name-conflict tags

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags, synonym-request

[name-clash](/questions/tagged/name-clash) and [name-conflict](/questions/tagged/name-conflict) mean the same thing. They should be merged, and [name-clash](/questions/tagged/name-clash) set as synonym of [name-conflict](/questions/tagged/name-conflict).